# Sync a ClearCase tree to Git (downward sync only)

Tags: git, clearcase

I already found numerous solutions that may answer my question, but they all appear very obscure to me. Most of them are inadequately documented and I am not ready to deep dive into the code to understand how they exactly work. So I decided write a program to sync a ClearCase tree into a Git repository.

On ClearCase non UCM, only labels are relevant because they are the only information that allow to glue files together. Later I can also look at the timestamp of each file and guess from their comment if they belong to the same commit.

So my first step is to dump a ClearCase tree history with these information:

- File name
- Branch
- Version number
- Label
- Author
- Comment

I think it can be done with this command:

```
cleartool find . \
    -exec 'ct lshistory \
        -fmt "[%n]\nHost:\t%h\nLabel:\t%l\nUser:\t%u\nComment:\t%c\n" \         
        %CLEARCASE_XPN% \
    '
```

Once I have a good dump I can write my Git Sync Tool that will import everything into a Git repository with all the branches and the labels.

Unfortunately I am not satisfied of my ClearCase dump command yep. 
Does anyone can help me?

From the solutions found on the Internet I considered [git-cc](https://github.com/charleso/git-cc) that looked promising. Unfortunately there is no documentation and after hours spent on it I still did not understand how it works. Perhaps [charleso](https://stackoverflow.com/users/297695/charleso) can help me with it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [clearcase-gitcc](https://github.com/nowox/clearcase-gitcc) which works on ClearCase non UCM. The command:

```
git ccpull
```

fetch the changes made on your ClearCase repository and the command

```
git ccpush
```

submit your `HEAD` to your ClearCase view in a similar way as `clearfsimport`.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the branch (with [`fmt_ccase`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/fmt_ccase.htm?cp=SSSH27_7.1.1%2F9-0-0-6-6)) which seems to be missing from your output (and that you mentioned in your list):

```
%Sn
```

> Short name: For a version, a short form of the version ID: `branch-pathname/version-number`. For other objects, the null string.

Couple of comments:

- A non-UCM label doesn't have to be put on *all* the files: a modification could have been done at the same time of the label, and yet not have been labelled (only a baseline full would set a label on all files of a component)
- a `cleartool find` will list only visible elements in the view: you might miss the history of deleted elements in past revisions.